# Iterate through an array and add new items to the array

Tags: linux, debian, array

I have an array setup:

```
target_array=(
    "item1 -a100 -b250 -caaa"
    "item2 -a110 -cbbb -d1sa"
    "item3 -d2sa -exxx -fyyy"
)
```

I then iterate over the array and perform various actions:

```
for target_item in "${target_array[@]}"; do
    #Do Stuff Here
    #and create new items
    x=111
    y=222
    z=333
done
```

Inside the loop I get new variables and need to add them to the array, so I would end up with something like:

```
target_array=(
    "item1 -a100 -b250 -caaa -x111 -y222 -z333"
    "item2 -a110 -cbbb -d1sa -x112 -y223 -z334"
    "item3 -d2sa -exxx -fyyy -x113 -y224 -z335"
)
```

But how can I add these items to the array? 
Should I be adding them to the existing array, or creating a new array?

I'm trying to port a script from `powershell` where I would use an 'object' that contained items (item1) and properties (-a) with values (100). But couldn't see a Linux equivalent so an array seemed to be the next best thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using `bash` you can iterate over the array using indices, instead of values, with construct `${!array[@]}`, and then just replace each element with new value:

```
for target_item in "${!target_array[@]}"; do
    x=111
    y=222
    z=333
    target_array["$target_item"]+=" -x$x -y$y -z$z"
done
```

Unfortunately it's not possible in `bash` to unfold index of an array element from its value.

---

In `zsh` you can simplify the procedure with a special so called *subscript flag* `(i)` and loop over an array normally:

```
for target_item in "${target_array[@]}"; do
     x=111                    
     y=222                    
     z=333
     i="${target_array[(i)$target_item]}"
     target_array[$i]+=" -x$x -y$y -z$z"
done
```

Comment: cheers, what does the `!` in front of `target_array` do?

Comment: @IGGt it means to iterate over array indices, not values.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new array in the loop and then setting the original array to this new array:

```
target_array=(
    "item1 -a100 -b250 -caaa"
    "item2 -a110 -cbbb -d1sa"
    "item3 -d2sa -exxx -fyyy"
)

for target_item in "${target_array[@]}"; do
    # Do Stuff Here
    # and create new items
    x=111
    y=222
    z=333

    new_array+=( "$target_item -x$x -y$y -z$z" )
done

target_array=( "${new_array[@]}" )
```

Using `/bin/sh` (because I prefer the syntax required to work with `$@` over `bash`'s somewhat bulky array syntax):

```
set -- \
    "item1 -a100 -b250 -caaa" \
    "item2 -a110 -cbbb -d1sa" \
    "item3 -d2sa -exxx -fyyy"

for target_item do
    # Do Stuff Here
    # and create new items
    x=111
    y=222
    z=333

    set -- "$@" "$target_item -x$x -y$y -z$z"
    shift
done
```

The modified array is `"$@"`.